# MYSQL autoincrement a column or just have an integer, difference?

Tags: mysql

If I have a column, set as primary index, and set as INT.

If I don't set it as auto increment and just insert random integers which are unique into it, does that slow down future queries compared to autincrementing?

Does it speed things up if I run **OPTIMIZE** on a table with its primary and only index as INT? (assuming only 2 columns, and second column is just some INT value)

(the main worry is the upper limit on the autoincrement as theres lots of adds and deletes in my table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't set it as auto increment and just insert random integers which are unique into it, does that slow it down compared to autincrementing?

In `MyISAM` it will in fact speed it (marginally).

In `InnoDB`, this may slow the `INSERT` operations down due to page splits.

This of course implies that your numbers are really unique.

> Does it speed things up if I optimise a table with its primary and only index as INT? (assuming only 2 columns, and second column is just some INT value)

`AUTO_INCREMENT` and `INT` may be used together.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` will compact you table and indexes, freeing the space left from the deleted rows and page splits. If you had lots of `DELETE` operations on the table or `INSERT` out of order (like in your solution with random numbers), this will help.

It will also bring the logical and physical order of the index pages into consistency with each other which will speed up full scans or ranged queries on `PK` (`PK BETWEEN val1 AND val2`), but will hardly matter for random seeks.

> (the main worry is the upper limit on the autoincrement as theres lots of adds and deletes in my table)

`BIGINT UNSIGNED` (which can also be used with `AUTO_INCREMENT`) may hold up values up to `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: bigint takes too many bytes and would slow down my DB.  Sorry, for the second comment, I meant to emphasize the OPTIMIZE part, meaning if i optimize (thereby sorting the random numbers in order in the table) would that speed things up at all?

Comment: @David: how many inserts and updates per second are you expecting?

Comment: inserts and updates will continue until the system slows too much, about 50 per second for now is expected. but I would like the question to relate to query vs. query on the 2 table structures not specificly to my current system please.

Comment: @David19801: Except for extremely general or obvious questions, there *is* no Single Right Answer, independent of the specifics. The parameters of *your* intended use are crucial.

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit for autoincremented integers is `18446744073709551615`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Are you really hitting such limit? If you do, allowing MySQL to add one to the previous number is an algorithm that can hardly improve.

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit on AUTOINCREMENT is the upper limit on the number type in the respective column. Even with `INT UNSIGNED`, this can take a while to hit; with `BIGINT` it's going to be very hard to reach that (and seriously, what kind of app are you building that 4 extra bytes per row are way too much?). So, if you're going to hit that limit, you'll hit it with autoincrement or without it.

Also, although not having AUTOINCREMENT will speed your inserts up a tiny bit, I'm willing to bet that any code to generate a unique integer to use instead of the AUTOINCREMENT will slow down the code more than the autoincrement would (generating random *non-conflicting* numbers will get progressively harder as your table fills up).

In other words, IMNSHO this looks like premature optimization, and will not significantly contribute to faster code (if at all), but it will make it less maintainable (as the PK will need to be generated explicitly, instead of the database taking care of it).